An old movie about a father who goes to the moon
I need to find this movie I used to love as a child and I've been searching for so long, without finding it. The movie is about a father who leaves his daughter to go to the moon (or outer space) and he has her fiance with him. While up there something (I cant remember) goes horribly wrong and in the end the father dies and sends her fiance back home. 
I don't remember that much, because I was so young, however the movie used to go on TV from time to time. I really do hope someone out there can help me find this movie!

Welcome to Movies & TV. You might want to add what "old" is and when you were a child. Or likewise what country it was likely from or any other details you might remember, if any.

Armageddon sounds like a likely candidate...

The heat from the asteroid's approach to earth damages the triggering device, forcing someone to stay behind to manually detonate the bomb. After all the non-flight crew volunteers, they draw straws, and A.J. (Ben Affleck, the Fiancé) is selected. 
As he and Harry (Bruce Willis, the Father) exit the airlock, Harry rips off A.J.'s air hose and
  shoves him back inside, telling him he is the son Harry never had, and
  he would be proud to have A.J. marry Grace. Harry prepares to detonate
  the bomb and contacts Grace to bid his final farewells. After the
  Freedom moves to a safe distance, Harry presses the button at the last
  minute, and the bomb successfully splits the asteroid to avoid
  collision with Earth as planned. Freedom lands, and the surviving crew
  are treated as heroes.
A.J. and Grace get married, with photos of Harry and the other lost
  crew members present in memoriam.


Whoa, now Armageddon is already being called "old", I guess this applies to me then, too. But well, the OP didn't mention what "old" is and when he was "a child" anyway, so +1 for likely the correct answer (or the possibility for an interesting reference-style question if that's not the answer).

I was thinking of Armageddon too. Great movie! I'll be curious to see whether this is what the OP was thinking of. To me, the "father/daughter/fiancée story" was important but the "earth is going to be destroyed" story got my attention more. After all, it's called "Armageddon", not "The Men I Love".
